# jQuery UI Autocomplete - tooltip is showing ALL entrys from list, even that not matching

Tags: jquery, user-interface, autocomplete

Autocomplete bubble is showing up, but when I type something in input, tooltip is showing ALL entrys from list, even that not matching... for ex. I can type: "aaaazzzz" and still have autocomplete bubble (in list there is NO such string)... There is more than 1600 users/elements in users.txt - but problem occurs even when I reduced list to 5 entrys. My script is:

```
$( "#userLogin" ).autocomplete({
    source: 'users.txt'
});
```

users.txt:

```
["user1","user2","user3"]
```

Related to: [jQuery UI Autocomplete - get data from txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682901/jquery-ui-autocomplete-get-data-from-txt-file)

Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: - Check this answer may help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371214/getting-jquery-autocomplete-to-work-with-php-source/10774401#10774401

Answer (score 1):

Jquery doesn't work well with txt files, you need to first break the data from the txt file into an array and then use that array as the source:

```
    var availableTags;
    $.get("Array.txt", function(data) {
        availableTags = data.split(',');
         $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({source:availableTags})
     });
```