# how to connect jquery ui auto-complete widget with database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

upload.php

```
<?php
include('lib.php');

$text = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['term']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE area LIKE (:keyword) ORDER BY id ASC 
LIMIT 0, 10";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$json = '[';
$first = true;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
if (!$first) { $json .=  ','; } else { $first = false; }
$json .= '{"value":"'.$row['area'].'"}';
 }
 $json .= ']';
 echo $json;
 ?>
```

area_list.js

```
$(function(){

   var test=["red","blue","pink","Black" ,"Grey"];  


   $("#term2").autocomplete({

    source:'<?php include upload_where.php; ?>'


    });


 });
```

HTML

```
<input id="term2" placeholder="e.g New Delhi, Mumbai" />
```

If you think the code is right is it possible maybe my server doesn't support json because i haven't used json before.

Comment: **[Try this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371214/getting-jquery-autocomplete-to-work-with-php-source)**

Answer (score 1):

You can't include your php in javascript.
So you need to create a php script for autocomplete.
In this script, its better using an array to store your results then convert it to json using "json_encode".

autocomplete.php :

```
<?php
include('lib.php');

if(true === isset($_GET['term']) && false === empty($_GET['term']))
{
    $text = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['term']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE area LIKE (:keyword) ORDER BY id ASC 
    LIMIT 0, 10";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    $json = array();
    $first = true;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        $json[] = $row['area'];
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($json);
}
?>
```

For the javascript, use ajax to retrieve your results

```
$('#term2').autocomplete({    
        minChars:2,
        noCache: false, //default is false, set to true to disable caching    
        // callback functions:
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "autocomplete.php", //Correspond to PHP page
                dataType: "json",
                data: {term: request.term},
                success: function(data) {
                            return data;
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You were using a string as input but you do need an array as autocomplete source.

If you don't want to code an ajax request, and **if your js is generated on the fly by php**, you can replace your code by this one:

```
$(function(){
   var test=["red","blue","pink","Black" ,"Grey"];  
   $("#term2").autocomplete({
    source:<?php include upload_where.php; ?>
    });
 });
```

However **it's not a good idea to use php to generate your js**. So you can use ThinkTank answer's

Comment: and is your js code generated by PHP or just a static file ?

Comment: i dont know, when i use array as a source in java script it works but when i try to use database as a source it doesnot work.

Comment: there is no property `"label"` in your json