# JQuery Autocomplete PHP source issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to use JQuery autocomplete feature using separate php script as source. When I use static table directly in JQuery as source, it works flawlessly:

```
$(function() {
   $( ".auto" ).autocomplete({
     source: ["Choice1", "Choice2"],
     minLength: 1
   });
});
```

But when I change the source to the php file (which is located in the same folder), the autocomplete feature doesn't seem to work.

```
$(function() {
   $( ".auto" ).autocomplete({
     source: 'search.php',
     minLength: 1
   });
});
```

Here is rest of my code related to autocomplete

Input field:

```
<tr>
    <div class="ui-widget">
       <td class="tg-031e"><form action="" method="post"><input type="text" class="txtbox auto ui-autocomplete-input" value=""/></form></td>
    </div>
</tr>
```

Php script:

```
<?php
    include_once 'php/database_connect.php';
    $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

    $query = $conn->query("SELECT type FROM material");
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
       $data[] = $row['type'];
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

P.S. Its not up to database connection *($conn)*, because I use it in other scripts without any problem.

Comment: how is it getting the get variable through that source url? try search.php?term=????

Comment: it is not even used now, I pass it just for filtering the results in future. It should list all rows from table

Comment: don't you use type ahead

Comment: @RahulSingh I don't get what do you mean, but if I put PHP code inside HTML, with the same SQL query, it returns correct data.

Comment: did you check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371214/getting-jquery-autocomplete-to-work-with-php-source